# Model in Rails 4 validating optional associations when they are not included

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms

I have a nested form in my Rails app for an Events model that allows the user to specify fields for Recurrence (another model) when the event recurs. Everything is working fine on creating the event, but it's giving me errors on updating the event when the event does not recur (and therefore does not want to save the relationship). I have recurrence set up to validate that the field "frequency" is present. When there is no recurrence, this field is left blank, but the form still kicks back and says that frequency needs to be there. Help?

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :recurrence
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :recurrence
end

class Recurrence < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
  validates :frequency, :presence => true
end
```

*from Events controller*

```
def event_params
  params.require(:event).permit(
    :name, :start, :duration, :unit, :location, :description, :major,
    recurrence_attributes: [ :frequency, :end ])
end

def update
  @event = Event.find(params[:id])

  if @event.recurrence && !params.has_key?(:has_recurrence)
    @event.recurrence.destroy 
  end

  if @event.update(event_params)
    redirect_to event_path(@event)
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

You will note that it is checking for the presence of a param called "has_recurrence" - This is a checkbox tag that I have in the form, outside of the model, to determine whether or not a recurrence should be saved for the event. If the user checks the box, the form will attempt to save the recurrence but if they do not check the box, the form will not save the recurrence (at least that's the idea).

The problem is that when I submit the form to edit an event, when the event is not recurring and the has_recurrence box is not checked, it still attempts to validate the recurrence and gives me back a validation error:

```
Recurrence frequency can't be blank
```

**UPDATE**
I have updated my recurrence model to validate conditionally, based on the answer below:

```
class Recurrence < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event

  validates :frequency, :presence => true, :if => :has_recurrence

  def has_recurrence=( yesorno=false )
    @has_recurrence = yesorno
  end

  def has_recurrence
    @has_recurrence ||= false
  end
end
```

And the update in my Events Controller is as follows...

```
def update

  @event = Event.find(params[:id])

  if @event.recurrence && !@has_recurrence 
    @event.recurrence.destroy
  end

  if @event.update(event_params)
    redirect_to event_path(@event)
  else
    flash[:notice] = @event.errors
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

And the view contains the following to check if there is a recurrence:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= check_box_tag "has_recurrence", nil, false %> Is this a recurring event? (must check to save recurrence)
</div>
<%= f.fields_for :recurrence do |builder| %>
  <%= render 'recurrence_fields', f: builder %>
<% end %>
```

And now, when recurrence is not checked I do not get a validation error, but the recurrence is saving to the database (with everything blank but the event_id)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a conditional validation and a custom attribute.  See: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#conditional-validation.  Doing that gets the validation code out of your controller and back into the model where it belongs.

Basically something similar to this (the example is not tested) should work:

```
validates :frequency, :presence => true, :if => :has_recurrence

def has_recurrence=( yesorno=false )
  @has_recurrence = yesorno
end

def has_recurrence
  @has_recurrence ||= false
end
```

Personally I would rename the attribute to `has_recurrence?` but that is simply style.

Comment: I will give this a shot. Do you have the two has_recurrence methods as options (one or the other) or are both needed?

Comment: You can do it all in one method if you do not wish to employ the = syntax in the assignment.  But that really is not idiomatic Ruby.  You can also use the `attr_accessor` meta method to generate both getter and setter methods at once, but that means you cannot set the defaults in the methods as I have done. It is really a matter of taste.

Comment: Ok - last question - my assumption is that I will need to set this value in my controller as in... @event.has_recurrence = true if params.has_key?(:has_recurrence) - is that a good assumption?

Comment: Or would that be set automatically by the form attribute?

Comment: No.  You do not need to and should not do that.  Custom attributes can be passed down to the form and back to the model just like any other attribute.  They simply will not be stored in the database.  Pass it like any other param and send it back to the model to handle.

Comment: Well, it seems to have worked, somewhat. The problem I have now is that it is inserting an invalid record into the database when has_recurrence is not selected. It's still putting it in, it just isn't validating it.

Comment: Clarify; what is happening exactly?

Comment: Have you set the `:include_hidden` tag on the checkbox for `has_recurrences` in the form?  HTML does not return checkbox params if they are not selected.  This tag compensates for that.  I thought that this was automatic in Rails4 but maybe not.

Comment: No, I didn't - my initial method was to check for its existence. I will try that

Comment: This finally worked when I made the check box part of the form builder and not a separate tag